# Sorting TableView Rows

Tags: swift, uitableview, sorting, parse-platform, xcode8

---- ANSWERED ----

I am currently trying to sort my tableview by the words on their labels they have. Each row will have at least one of the 9 colors a user can choose (user can choose as many as they want). I have a specific order in mind on how I want to organize the table, but depending on which row the user picks first, the order of the rows can be anything (the problem).

What I was thinking was that I make an array in the order I want the words to show in the second screen: "red, blue, green,...." then somehow connect this array to the tableview. So if the tableview were to follow this order (red, blue, green,....), and the user does pick blue, the table will be ordered as "red, green,...". Meaning that no matter what colors the user has or doesn't have, the tableview will follow the order of the array. I tried googling a solution for this problem for days and can not seem to figure it out. Any suggestions? I have pasted my code of how the colors load:

```
func loadColors() {
        let colorQuery = PFQuery(className: "Colors")
        colorQuery.whereKey("userID", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.objectId! ?? String()) //getting which user
        colorQuery.limit = 10
        colorQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.colorTypeArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self.colorNameArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)                
                self.colorObjectIDArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

                for object in objects! {
                    self.colorTypeArray.append(object.value(forKey: "colorType") as! String) // add data to arrays
                    self.colorNameArray.append(object.value(forKey: "colorName") as! String) // add data to arrays                    
                    self.colorObjectIDArray.append(object.objectId!) //appends the objectid
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            } else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? String())
            }
        }
    }

//places colors in rows
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! ColorsCell //connects to color cell

        cell.colorType.text = colorTypeArray[indexPath.row] //goes through array and puts colors on cell label

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, the user has a list of colors that they can add more colors to. Your goal is to make sure that even as the user adds arbitrary colors to the list, they maintain some order that you have predefined.

Here is a simplified example of how I would handle this. Basically, as you said in your question, you must defined an array of colors which will be used as a reference to know the correct order (`patternColors` below).

Then, when your list of colors changes (e.g. you retrieved the list from the server, or the user added or removed a color), re-sort the list as shown below.

```
func sort(colors: [String]) -> [String] {

    // This is the order I want the colors to be in.
    var patternColors = ["Red", "Blue", "Green"]

    // We use `map` to convert the array of three colors into
    // an array of subarrays. Each subarray contains all the 
    // colors that match that particular pattern color (we use
    // `filter` to find all these matching colors.
    // Finally, we use `flatMap` to convert this array of 
    // subarrays back into a normal one-dimensional array.
    var sortedColors = patternColors.map { patternColor in
        colors.filter { color in
            color == patternColor
        }
    }.flatMap { $0 }

    return sortedColors
}


var unsortedColors = ["Blue", "Red", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Red"]

let sortedColors = sort(colors: unsortedColors)
print(sortedColors) // ["Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Green"]
```

Comment: I added this in my code right after I gather the data and use print(sortedColors),  the array shows up empty

Comment: Is your code at fault or mine? Has `patternColors` got the right values for your case?

Comment: Ah im so sorry it was my code that had the issue! Thanks!